# How can I access my VS Code extension variables in javascript?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In package.json I have added properties that now show up under my Extension settings. For instance I have a setting (property) called "server". How can I access the setting as a variable in my extension.js script? I would like to call a server using that server-setting as base url.

Comment: you have to fetch the configuration and extract the named property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the setting like this:

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

const serverSetting = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('yourPackageName').server;
```

Comment: That import was unnecessary (actually gave me an error), but the other worked fine. Thank you very much!